# Set cookie in flask redirect() to external page

Tags: python, flask, cookies

I try to redirect user to https://exampleurl.com and open already authenticated page.
I get authenticated cookie with

```
url = 'https://exampleurl.com'
response = session.post(url, json=auth_data, params=params, headers=headers) #successfull login
auth_cookie = str(session.cookies.get_dict()["ITLA"])
```

And then try to redirect and pass cookie to site

```
response = redirect(url)
response.set_cookie("ITLA", auth_cookie)
return response
```

But "ITLA" cookie does not appear on the page to which I redirect the user.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I gues this is not possible, as you can not force the creation of cookies on another website.

Comment: But if I open exampleurl.com and add cookie from auth_cookie in application/cookies in devtools in chrome, after page reload I get authenticated main page. There is no way to do it in python?

Comment: There is a `SameSite` cookie option, that is probably set to strict, that restricts cookies from other sites to be sent to the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies (scroll down to SameSite cookies).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Erich. I need to redirect user to authenticated page, do you have any ideas on how to do it without cookie?